# spider won't follow link

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to logon a crawler training website. The account name can be anything, while the password is a number from 0 to 30. According to its requirement, I will have to try many times to find the password. So the spider needs to constantly try different password.

However, in my code, the spider will only try two times and stop. The first time is using start_requests and another time is using parse.

Could you please help me on this?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class heibanke2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "herbanke2"
#   start_urls = ["http://www.heibanke.com/lesson/crawler_ex01/"]
    password = 0


    def parse(self, response):
        print "enter parse"
        self.password+=1
        with open("try" + str(self.password), "wb") as f:
             f.write(response.body)
        yield Request(url="http://www.heibanke.com/lesson/crawler_ex01/", callback=self.parse, cookies={'username':str(1), "password":str(self.password)})

    def start_requests(self):
        print "prepared to login"
        yield Request(url="http://www.heibanke.com/lesson/crawler_ex01/", callback=self.parse, cookies={'username':str(1), "password":str(self.password)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is a *duplicate request filtering middleware* in action. Since the URL itself does not change, the subsequent requests are filtered. Pass [`dont_filter=True`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) to turn it off:

```
def parse(self, response):
    print "enter parse"
    self.password+=1
    with open("try" + str(self.password), "wb") as f:
         f.write(response.body)
    yield Request(url="http://www.heibanke.com/lesson/crawler_ex01/", 
                  callback=self.parse, 
                  cookies={'username':str(1), "password":str(self.password)},
                  dont_filter=True)  # HERE
```